# Doob Meyer decomposition in an exercise

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I have to find the Doob Meyer decomposition for the following process:

$Y_t=e^{(1+B_t^2)}$

I think that the method is to derive with the Ito's formula the process and I've obtained:

$dY_t=2B_te^{(1+B_t^2)}dB_t+e^{1+B_t^2}(1+2B^2_t)dt$

I want the process in an explicit mode (not with the integral). Is there a general method to do this with other process?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.